# Where is Microsoft's useful documentation for IServiceCollection.Add(new ServiceDescriptor(...))?

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, asp.net-core-webapi

I am working on an existing WebAPI project and inside

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
```

the IoC container is setup like so

```
services.Add(new ServiceDescriptor(typeof(ISQLConnectionFactory), new SQLConnectionFactory(GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"))));
```

(there are also lots of services.AddScoped which I'm not asking about)

**Questions**

1. Where can I find Microsoft's documentation that explains the concepts behind "IServiceCollection.Add(new ServiceDescriptor ..." ([this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.extensions.servicecollectiondescriptorextensions.add?view=aspnetcore-2.2) is too little)

or perhaps someone can provide some insight

1. What does „services.Add(new ServiceDescriptor ...“ do ?
2. What is a ServiceDescriptor ?
3. By debugging the code, I see that SQLConnectionFactory is only instantiated once. Does the call "services.Add" (always) create a singleton object? If so what is the difference to services.AddSingleton?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What does „services.Add(new ServiceDescriptor ...“ do ?

For detail information about `services.Add`, you could refer the source code [Add](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/blob/master/src/DependencyInjection/DI.Abstractions/src/Extensions/ServiceCollectionDescriptorExtensions.cs).

```
public static IServiceCollection Add(
    this IServiceCollection collection,
    ServiceDescriptor descriptor)
{
    if (collection == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(collection));
    }

    if (descriptor == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(descriptor));
    }

    collection.Add(descriptor);
    return collection;
}
```

For this code, it add the `ServiceDescriptor` to the `ServiceCollection`.

> What is a ServiceDescriptor ?

`ServiceDescriptor` describes a service with its service type, implementation, and lifetime. It will be used to initializes a new instance of ServiceDescriptor with the specified implementationType.

> By debugging the code, I see that SQLConnectionFactory is only instantiated once. Does the call "services.Add" (always) create a singleton object? If so what is the difference to services.AddSingleton?

This depends on whehter you pass the scope for `services.Add`. The default scope for `services.add` is `ServiceLifetime`. You could descipe the service with different scope by passing `ServiceLifetime` like `services.Add(new ServiceDescriptor(typeof(ISQLConnectionFactory), new SQLConnectionFactory(GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")), ServiceLifetime.Scoped));`

There is no different between `services.Add` and `AddSingleton`. The `AddSingleton` just call `services.Add` with passing `ServiceLifetime.Singleton`

```
public static IServiceCollection AddSingleton(
    this IServiceCollection services,
    Type serviceType,
    Type implementationType)
{
    if (services == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(services));
    }

    if (serviceType == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(serviceType));
    }

    if (implementationType == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(implementationType));
    }

    return Add(services, serviceType, implementationType, ServiceLifetime.Singleton);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This link could provide some explanations
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.2

- `services.Add(` adds new dependency registration that later can be resolved
- `new ServiceDescriptor` [constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicedescriptor.-ctor?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_ServiceDescriptor__ctor_System_Type_System_Type_Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_ServiceLifetime_) provide explicit registration with the factory that will supply new instances and lifetime description
- `services.AddSingleton` is just a shorthand for doing this with a defined lifetime as [Singleton](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicelifetime?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_ServiceLifetime_Singleton)